# Missing Operating System message while booting

Tags: boot, usb, liveusb

I just erased my whole disk drive and I created a single unpartitioned space to my hard drive using GParted(http://gparted.org) usb stick (which proves that this system can boot from usb).
The problem is that whenever I try to boot from my usb drive (fat32) to try either windows 10 technical preview or windows 8.1 the system bypass the usb stick and displays the message Missing Operating System (because it arrives at the 3rd boot option, the internal hard drive - 1st is external device and 2nd is optical disk).
Any ideas?
Thank you.